# Turning strings into lists but joining elements if they meet certain conditions

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner in Python and coding in general, so I feel like I'm out of my depth with this problem. I'm trying to make a list out of a string but with some modifications.

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
input_text = "gʷʰsoʷngʲʷʰos"
modifiers_list = ["ʷ", "ʰ", "ʲ"]
```

I would like to be able to turn the input text into a list of characters, but with modifiers being a part of the preceding characters, e.g.:

```
output_list = ['gʷʰ', 's', 'oʷ', 'n', 'gʲʷʰ', 'o', 's']
```

I've been trying to come up with a solution for a few days now, looking through numerous SO threads but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
import re

modifiers = ''.join(map(re.escape, modifiers_list))
pattern = r'\w(?:[{}])*'.format(modifiers)
output_list = re.findall(pattern, input_text)

print(output_list)  # ['gʷʰ', 's', 'oʷ', 'n', 'gʲʷʰ', 'o', 's']
```

The pattern that's constructed looks like `\w(?:[ʷʰʲ])*`, and it matches a single character followed by any number of modifiers.